# Access SPList.RootFolder.Properties from Client

Tags: list, web-services, properties

Is there a way to access the **SPList.RootFolder.Properties** key/value pair collection from a client, either via **Lists.asmx** or the new **client object model**?

I know I can create my own **ISAPI endpoint** and implement access, but I'd prefer to use pre-existing functionality if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [List.RootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.rootfolder.aspx) class which will get you the Root Folder of the list. And there is the [Folder.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.properties.aspx) class which should get you the properties of the Root Folder.

So you should be able to access it using: `List.RootFolder.Properties`

Comment: Those classes are for server-side code. My question is about client applications that query the SharePoint server for this information.

Comment: Those classes are part of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll which can be used in client applications.